# StackOverflowError with Maven 3.3.9, Java 8 and Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, java-8, maven-3, stack-overflow

I get an `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when I try to compile and package my code with `mvn package` and Java 1.8.0_112.

My code compiles well with Java 7.

I tried to set `JAVA_OPTS=-Xss512m` and tried with 1G as well but always get the same error.

The code is written in Scala and I am using these versions in my pom.xml:

```
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    <spark.version>1.6.0-cdh5.7.1</spark.version>
    <hbase.version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.1</hbase.version>
    <kafka.version>0.9.0.0</kafka.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.2</jackson.version>
    <iodadm.version>05.4.1</iodadm.version>
```

I tried also with Scala version 2.12.0 because 2.10.x is not compatible with Java 8.

part of the error stack:

```
INFO] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:164)
[INFO]  at scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:116)
[INFO]  at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Printers$class.render(Printers.scala:168)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Universe.render(Universe.scala:59)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.api.Printers$class.show(Printers.scala:190)
```

One more thing, stackoverflow error is usually a runtime execution error, how is it possible to get it during compilation ?

[Added 1]   I found that this error is caused by scala classes with at least 150 properties

[Added 2] The function throwing this error is equals function, i developed it like this:

```
def equals(other:MyClass):Boolean = {
  this.P1 == other.P1 &&
  this.P2 == other.P2 &&
  ... ~ 180 similar line ...
  this.P180 == other.P180
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us some more details about that ```StackOverflowError```? Some reproducible sample code would be great. Otherwise the question is too broad and I doubt that someone could give you a valuable answer.

Comment: BTW: a ```StackOverflowError``` usually occurs when you have e.g. endless recursions somewhere. In that case it would not matter to increase the stack size. You would always get the same error until you fix the root cause.

Comment: @h3nrik: Thank's for the advice. but the project is big and i can't know which part of the code is throwing this error. Besides, the code is working well with java 7. i edited the answer with a part of the error stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by splitting the logical operation in many

```
def equals(other:MyClass):Boolean = {
   Boolean bool1=this.P1 == other.P1 && 
     this.P2 == other.P2 &&
     ...
     this.P100 == other.P100
   Boolean bool2=this.P101 == other.P101 && 
     this.P102 == other.P102 &&
     ...
     this.P200 == other.P200   

  bool1 && bool2
}
```

The approach to solve this type of problems is to compile the code gradually till finding the code bloc that throws the error

I hope this will help someone